# How do I use Rust code in Node.js such that the Rust function accepts a JavaScript function as a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust, callback, ffi

It would look something like this in Rust; `handler` would come from JavaScript:

```
let url = "127.0.0.1:4445"; // JavaScript url
let address = SocketAddr::from_str(url).await.unwrap();
let listener = Listener::bind(&address).await.unwrap();
let mut result = false;
while let Some(stream) = listener.incoming().next().await {
    handler(conn); // JavaScript handler
}
```

I'm planning to use FFI for the integration in Node.js, but I'm not sure how to use the JavaScript function as a callback from Rust.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is it safe to pass js callback to a ffi function which calls it in another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38973254/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Let me check it out if this is what I need(Should take a few days due to vacation) and I will get back to it. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster Yeah this is what I was looking for. You can mark the question as answered.